# Como remover todos os itens de uma relação many-to-many no Django?

Tags: python, django, model

Tenho os seguintes models na minha aplicação Django:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tags'
        ordering = ('name', )


class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    text  = models.TextField()
    user  = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='questions')
    tags  = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

No caso, `Question` tem `N` relacionamentos com `N` tags. Supondo que na Question 1 eu tenha relacionamento com as tags 1, 2 e 3, como eu faria para remover todas as tags relacionadas a Question?

Exemplo:

```
 question = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
 # Quero desassociar  todas as tags dessa questão
```

Answer (score 2):

Para remover todas as tags relacionadas o [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.clear) oferece a funçao `clear` que remove todos os objetos do conjunto de objetos relacionados sem deletar as relações apenas só removendo a associação, caso você queira remover e deletar os objetos relacionados use a funçao `remove`, alguns exemplos pra esclarecer a idéia

**Remove apenas as associações(as tags ainda vão existir)**

```py
>>> question = Question.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> question.tags.clear()
>>> question.tags.all()
<QuerySet []>
>>> Tag.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Tag: 1>, <Tag: 2>, <Tag: 3>]>
```

**Remove as associações e deleta as tags(as tags não vão mais existir)**

```py
question = Question.objects.get(pk=1)

# deleta as tags 
for tag in question.tags.all():
    tag.delete()

Tag.objects.all() # retorna <QuerySet []>
```

Eu testei a função `remove` e não funcionou, então fiz esse código acima pra remover manualmente.